# Not defined in logarithmic differentiation

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

The derivative of $\ln x^x$ by logarithmic differentiation is $\ln x^x[\ln(\ln(x)+(1/\ln x)]$ but what will be derivative when $x=1$ and at small values like $0.00001$ because $\ln (x)$ is negative and $\ln (\ln (x))$ is not defined.

Comment: Are you looking at $(\ln x)^x$ or $\ln( x^x)$?  The former is not well defined for most $x<1$ as it involves irrational exponents of negative numbers

Comment: For $x=1$ you can find the limit of the function ${{\left(\ln x\right) }^{x}}\left( \ln\left( \ln x \right) +\frac{1}{\ln x}\right)$ as $x \to 1^+$

Answer (score 1):

When you are taking logarithm both sides, it is assumed both sides are positive, because of the domain of $ln()$.

Now find out when $\ln\left(x^{x}\right)$ is positive. or $x^{x}>1$